# How to put an argument of a function inside a raw string

Tags: python, regex, string, variables

I want to create a function that will delete a character in a string of text.
I'll pass the string of text and the character as arguments of the function.
The function works fine but I don't know how to do this correctly if I want to threat it as a raw string.

For example:

```
import re

def my_function(text, ch):    
    Regex=re.compile(r'(ch)')   # <-- Wrong, obviously this will just search for the 'ch' characters
    print(Regex.sub('',r'text'))      # <-- Wrong too, same problem as before. 


text= 'Hello there'
ch= 'h'

my_function(text, ch)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

How about changing:

```
Regex=re.compile(r'(ch)')
print(Regex.sub('',r'text'))
```

to:

```
Regex=re.compile(r'({})'.format(ch))
print(Regex.sub('',r'{}'.format(text)))
```

However, simpler way to achieve this is using `str.replace()` as:

```
text= 'Hello there'
ch= 'h'
text = text.replace(ch, '')
# value of text: 'Hello tere'
```

Comment: Thanks the book that I'm going over didn't mention yet the alternative way of doing with a 'format' method. Guess I learn something new today.

Answer (score 2):

```
def my_function(text, ch): 
    text.replace(ch, "")
```

This will replace all occurrences of **ch** with an empty string.  No need to invoke the overhead of regular expressions in this.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. This is a much simpler and efficient way.